# Не работает POST запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery

В постмане все работает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    getQuestionWithoutTag(page, size, id) {
        let query = '/api/question/withTags?page=' + page + '&size=' + size ;
         fetch(query,{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body : [id]})
            .then(function(response) {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    let error = new Error();
                    error.response = response.text();
                    throw error;
                }
                return response.json();
            }).catch(error => error.response.then(message => console.log(message)));
    }
```

Ответ на запрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что значит "не работает"?

Comment: ошибка выходит `message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of "java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Long>" `

Comment: Ну значит надо смотреть что приходит на сервер и что происходит на сервере. Смотреть через дебаг почему он считает, что некорректный json пришёл

Comment: Просто странно в Postmane все работает)

Comment: а в постмане приходит ответ на запрос?

Comment: да приходит ответ, приложил фото